# str_replace in an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I was wondering if it is possible to do an str_replace within an array. I have a script that gets values from a CSV file and put it into a mysql database. However cells within the csv file might contain '-', in order to indicate that there is no value. The current script will, however, will import the value '-' into the mysql database. What i would like is that it will ignore the value '-' or replace it with '' (an empty cell value) so that no value is imported into the mysql databse.

This is what the current array looks like (part of the script). I would like to apply the filter to: `sub_sub_category`

```
public function setFields($dir = 'import')

  {

    $timeNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if ($this->v14)

      $this->_path = realpath(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/'.$dir).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    else

      $this->_path = realpath(PS_ADMIN_DIR.'/'.$dir).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $this->psFields1a = array(
'sub_sub_category' => $this->l('Sub-sub-category'));
}
```

I hope it is clear what i mean and that it is a doable thing to do.
Thanks,
Robbert

Comment: Your question is about `str_replace` but didn't get it from your code, can you clarify ?

Comment: It is something i would like to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code demonstrates how you can remove all the "-" hyphens from an array using **array_walk**.

```
    function remove_dash(&$item, $key) {
        if($item === '-') $item = '';
    }

    $myArray = array("d" => "hello", "-", "b" => "test", "c" => "-");

    array_walk($myArray, 'remove_dash');
```

(hope I udnerstood the question)

Comment: Thanks, where should I put this function in my code? Inside or outside `public function`?

Comment: You should of course create the function 'remove_dash' outside the function setFields, and as it is a member function you should call it like this:

array_walk($myArray, array($this, 'remove_dash'));

Comment: Okay thanks. I placed the function below the function setFields and changed the array_walk. I am not very experienced with arrays, but when i put the code `function remove_dash(&$item, $key) {
        if($item === '-') $item = '';
    }

    $myArray = array("d" => "hello", "-", "b" => "test", "c" => "-");

    array_walk($myArray, array($this, 'remove_dash')); ` in the code it results in a blank page. Am i doing something wrong? thanks!

Comment: well first of all, add the following at the beginning of your scripts:
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
secondly, it's hard to tell without seeing the code, but have a look at this code that works: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aGrqzPML

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew, tried multiple things but the '_' is still there;) the code i have is too big, i guess, to post here. Thereby it is not a free code, so i cannot post it anywhere public i guess.. Thanks anyway for your help and i will keep trying!

Comment: @RobbertT is the problem solved? You need further help with array_walk?

Comment: Hi Matthew, well i did not get it to work, but i guess you array_walk is correct right? The array_walk function is a function that you put after the array right? It 're-walks' the previous array or do i understand it wrong? Thanks for your time!

Comment: array_walk allows you to modify directly each element of the array, with the means of a callback function that you specify. In my example above, I remove the dash characters of each element of the array with the callback function "remove_dash". You can find other examples here: http://us2.php.net/array_walk#refsect1-function.array-walk-examples

I don't really understand when you say "after the array", "previous array", etc. array_walk takes an array as argument, and allow you to modify each element from that same array.

Comment: Hey Matthew, thank you soo much for your clear explaination! I will play with it. What i meant with after or before an array is; am i supposed to put the array walk before or after the actual array? In my question `$this->psFields1a = array(` or should i implement it in that array? Thanks again

Comment: In your question, if $this->l('Sub-sub-category') returns an array containing elements with the '-' dash characters, you should do it on that.

Comment: So leave it out and replace it by the array_walk?

Comment: uhm I guess, it's quite trivial:)

Comment: Thanks Matthew, Looked up some more info about the array_walk and this really helped me a lot. I was not aware of the existence of this function. Thanks again for all your help! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that this is the right line you are looking at, but why not just do it as you are setting it?

```
$this->psFields1a = array(
sub_sub_category => str_replace('-','',$this->l('Sub-sub-category'))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, guess this is not the right place then because the '-' still shows up as sub-sub-category.